# Spring's method injection

Tags: java, spring

I'm reading the Spring current version's documentation and have problems with understanding of the chapter [5.4.6 Method Injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-method-injection). As far as I got we can provide the ability of recreation a bean every time we call the method using the bean. Documentation provides the following code example:

```
public class CommandManager implements ApplicationContextAware {

    //Imports and comments were omitted
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Object process(Map commandState) {
        Command command = createCommand();
        command.setState(commandState);
        return command.execute();
    }

    protected Command createCommand() {
        return this.applicationContext.getBean("command", Command.class);
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(
            ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

where `ApplicationContextAware` interface looks like:

```
public interface ApplicationContextAware {

    //JavaDocs ommited
    void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException;

}
```

So, what is the method `public Object process(Map commandState)`? Is it a callback? If so, where is it going to be called and who performs that call? After all, it's not clear why the bean is goign to be recreated every time it needed.

Answer (score 2):

The `Command` and `CommandManager` classes are just example classes, where `process()` is a part of that example. They have nothing to do with `ApplicationContextAware`.

Note the comment in the example for `CommandManager`:

```
// a class that uses a stateful Command-style class to perform some processing
```

`process()` is to be called by the application, somewhere else; it doesn't  matter for the sake of the example. If you are not using exactly the same model in your code, you should ignore this method and just call `applicationContext.getBean()` where applicable.

Finally, yes `CommandManager` should be registered as a bean in order for spring to call `setApplicationContext()`.

**edit**

> why does spring know that it have to recreate the bean with the name command every time

Given the contents of the example, it doesn't. The example code calls `getBean()`, which, according to [the javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-):

> Return an instance, which may be shared or independent, of the specified bean.

In order to ensure that you always get a new instance, you'll need to use the `prototype` scope.

```
<bean id="beanB class="Command" scope="prototype"/>
```

Comment: So, why does spring know that it have to recreate the bean with the name `command` every time it's being asked.

Comment: Should the `CommandManager` class be registered as a spring bean?

Answer (score 1):

Injection is happening actually here:

```
protected Command createCommand() {
    // notice the Spring API dependency!
    return this.applicationContext.getBean("command", Command.class);
}
```

We are just getting bean with different lifecycle in this method.

Comment: But who exactly calls the `process` method which itself calls the `createCommand`?

Comment: It's a public method. Just as an example. Imagine that this method will be called from another part of application. Or you call it in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring's suggestion

> A solution is to forego some inversion of control. You can make bean A aware of the container by implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface, and by making a getBean("B") call to the container ask for (a typically new) bean B instance every time bean A needs it.

solution for method get() could look like this:

```
public class SingletonA implements ApplicationContextAware {
        
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
        public PrototypeB getPrototypeB() {
            return applicationContext.getBean("prototypeB",PrototypeB.class);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }
    }
```

with beans defenition

```
<bean id="singletonA" class="di.methodinjection.SingletonA" autowire="byName"/>
<bean id="prototypeB" class="di.methodinjection.PrototypeB" scope="prototype"/>
```